# What could cause GDI+ Initialize exception

Tags: gdi+

I spend a lot of time to search answer but I didn't found it. We have console application (exe) with C1 Report Component for automated printing task. This application is executed from cmd file and cmd file is called by cmdexec from SQL Server 2014 every minute. It's work very fine but there is exceptiton GDI+ Initialize - System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.Initialize aproximetelly montly. There is no chance to solve this so we must restart server.

I tried to create cmd file with echo command. It was worked fine and I got output from echo. So I created application with Console.Writeline("Hello world") only. It was worked fine. Then I add reference to System.Drawing. Nothing happend - ouput was produced. Then I created System.Drawing.Bitmap object and I got GDI+ Initialize exception.

Job on SQL server run as SQLRUNSERVICES and it is in Administrator group. But when I log as SQLRUNSERVICES and launch our application in command line, application works fine without exception. When I log as another user there is no problem with this. Only with SQLRUNSERVICES throught SQL Proxy.

I suppose there must be something wrong with windows session. This application starts, prints some reports and finishes. So I suppose when application finishes memory will be free and GDI object will be free so. I check if we have call dispose method for each object working with GDI.

Can I have some chance to see GDI objects used by session? Or what could cause this exception? I cannot use task manager because when application is not running there is nothing to see.

Thank you for replies. It is very stresfull problem for us because it is going repeatedly every month after restart server.

Answer (score 0):

We created testing application to print most quickly and we got this exception for one day. We call Dispose method for C1Report ofcourse. We will try to use using section. But it looks like C1 error. Test application printed about 65000 count of document and then crashed by GDI+ Initialization Exception. There is stack:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Initialize()
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0(Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 stride, Int32 format, HandleRef scan0, IntPtr& bitmap)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at C1.C1Preview.GraphicsHolder.FromBitmap()
   at C1.C1Preview.GraphicsHolder.FromScreen()
   at C1.C1Preview.C1PrintDocument.SelectBestMeasurementDevice(Boolean showWarning, MeasurementDeviceEnum& measurementDevice, String& measurementPrinterName, GraphicsHolder& measurementGraphicsHolder)
   at C1.C1Preview.C1PrintDocument.#fFe()
   at C1.C1Preview.C1PrintDocument.SetCreationDevice(MeasurementDeviceEnum creationDevice, String creationPrinterName)
   at C1.C1Report.Layout..ctor(C1Report report)
   at C1.C1Report.C1Report.Initialize()
   at C1.C1Report.C1Report..ctor()
```